# Binding YouTube Video to Div Element from Seperate JS file

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, youtube, phonejs, devextreme

I have this problem embedding YouTube video in a PhoneJS single-page mobile application. In PhoneJS, the JS scripts are defined in a different file. So I defined the HTML div like this:

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

Now in the JS file, I did this:

```
function getVideo() {        
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var playerDiv = document.getElementById('player');
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player(playerDiv, {
            height: '250',
            width: '444',
            videoId: sIFYPQjYhv8               
        });
    }        
}
```

When I run and view the debugger, the call is made to Youtube and response is received, but it is not displayed on the view.

Ok since I am using KnockoutJS binding, I modified the div in the html view like this:

```
<iframe id="player" type="text/html" width="444" height="250" frameborder="0" data-bind="attr: { src: src }"></iframe>
```

And then pass in the src video id thus:

```
src: ko.observable('http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + sIFYPQjYhv8 + '?autoplay=1')
```

In this case however, in the debugger, the call is not even made to Youtube. Nothing just happens. Actually I prefer to use the API call instead of the second approach.

Any suggestions on how to make the first approach work? I  mean using the API call?

EDIT
Just want to mention that when I add the code below in the view, the video is streamed alright.

```
<h1>Video</h1>
        <div id="player"></div>
        <script>
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var playerDiv = document.getElementById('player');
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            var player;
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                player = new YT.Player(playerDiv, {
                    height: '250',
                    width: '444',
                    videoId: 'sIFYPQjYhv8'
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use a custom binding handler with a flag set from the onYouTubeIFrameAPIReady callback

[Sample jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T5gmJ/)

```
ko.bindingHandlers['player'] = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // Check if global script and function is declared.
        if ( !document.getElementById('playerScript') ) {
            // Create script
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var playerDiv = document.getElementById('player');
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

            // Create global function that their API calls back
            window.playerReady = ko.observable(false);
            window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
                window.playerReady(true);
            };
        }
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        var value = valueAccessor(),
            id = value.id(),
            height = ko.unwrap(value.height) || '250',
            width = ko.unwrap(value.width) || '444'
        ;

        if ( !value.id()) {
            return;
        }

        if ( !window.playerReady() ) {
            // YT hasn't invoked global callback.  Subscribe to update
            var subscription;
            subscription = window.playerReady.subscribe( function(newValue) {
                 if ( newValue ) {
                     subscription.dispose();
                     // Just get this binding to fire again
                     value.id.notifySubscribers(value.id());
                 }
            });
        } else {

            var player = new YT.Player( element, {
                height: height,
                width: width,
                videoId: id 
            });
        }
    },
}
```

Now change your player div to

```
<div data-bind="player: { id: id, height: height, width: width }"></div>
```

Finally bind

```
var vm = { 
    id: 'sIFYPQjYhv8',
    height: '250',
    width: '444'
};
ko.applyBindings( vm )
```

---

**EDIT**

To remove the reliance on window, put your script tag that adds the new script element back, tweek as below, modify their callback and use a setTimeout instead of the "playerReady" observable

*HTML Script*

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
tag.setAttribute('id', 'playerScript');
tag.setAttribute('data-ready', 'false');
...

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    document.getElementById('playerScript').setAttribute('data-ready', 'true');
};
```

*Player Binding*

```
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        var value = valueAccessor(),
            id = value.id(),
            height = ko.unwrap(value.height) || '250',
            width = ko.unwrap(value.width) || '444',
            playerScript = document.getElementById('playerScript')
        ;

        if ( !value.id()) {
            return;
        }

        if ( !playerScript || playerScript.getAttribute('data-ready') !== 'true' ) ) {
            // YT hasn't invoked global callback.  
            setTimeout( function() {
                 value.id.notifySubscribers(value.id());
            }, 50);
        } else {

            var player = new YT.Player( element, {
                height: height,
                width: width,
                videoId: id 
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: this works perfect on an HTML document, and its a most elegant solution. Especially the ability bind the height and width. However, in the Devexpress PhoneJS application, it still does not work. It must be an issue with the PhoneJS framework? I have asked on their site and yet to receive response. For some illusive reason, it appears the JS file is not able to access the DIV in the HTML file. I await their response and will accept your answer as appropriate as soon as they respond. Thanks. The fiddle is awesome and I am sure I (and others) will be using it! Thanks a million!!!

Comment: Just to buttress the point above, that perhaps the problem is that the PhoneJS JS file is not able to access the player div in the html view, I added the this JQuery plugin that is supposed to auto-fit videos to their containing divs, from https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js I then called initialized it in the PhoneJS JS file, yet noting happens. So it must be PhoneJS!

Comment: Hi @robert-slaney, I really deserve to be punished by you severely for making you modify your earlier answer. And this is why: The way PhoneJS handles KO binding is slightly different (I mean the syntax). There is no calling of ko.applyBindings(). And that was what I kept missing. After modifying the binding, the first answer serves perfect! Aren't you a saviour? So Now the billions of thanks! And more thanks. Been awake for 28 hours to solve this! Aren't some people just super wonderful?

Comment: Glad to have help... in whatever twisted way it help you solve the issue!

Comment: Hi @robert-slaney, there is a nice little plugin here at [link]https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js that will automatically fit videos to a div element. I have unsuccessfully attempted to apply it to the 

`<div data-bind="player: { id: id, height: height, width: width }"></div>`

My thinking is there will be an elegant way to bind the div above to the fitdivs jQuery plugin, since I cant use: 

`$(document).ready(function(){
    // Target your .container, .wrapper, .post, etc.
    $("#thing-with-videos").fitVids();
  });`

Any help?

Comment: You have access to the element in the binding's update function.  You should be able to invoke it after the YT.player call  ie `$(element).fitVids()`

Comment: Hi. Thanks Robert! Saviour you are!